# Javascript event execution order

Tags: javascript, dom, events

What is the execution order of inline events, `attachEvent` handlers, and an `<a>` tag's `href`  navigation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/rhJ2f/

Comment: even the tag event return false, the binded handler still exec! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The execution order of individual event handlers is undefined.

If none of the event handlers called `e.preventDefault()`, and if `onclick` didn't `return false`, a navigation will occur.

Comment: I always thought tags event had priority over binded ones.

Comment: If using `attachEvent`, this implies IE, which means the event will have no `preventDefault` method. The equivalent is `e.returnValue = false;`.